# Android - SearchView in toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

I want to add a searchview into the toolbar. I want to expand the search view always. The body of onCreateOprionsMenu callback is below:

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(context);
searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
searchView.clearFocus();
searchView.setIconified(false);
searchView.clearFocus();

menuItem = optionsMenu.add(0, id, 0, title);
menuItem.setEnabled(item.enabled);
menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
menuItem.setActionView(searchView);
```

Screenshots are below:

[image]

Why the first close button of the searchview is visible but not other.?

Also after editing input text, I press the second close button and it collapsed the search view. Second clear button clears only text in edit text.

I couldn't fix this problem.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I'm trying to do something similar

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I couldn't remember :/

Comment: Provide more code please. Xml too